# Cytoscape - Adding Dynamic Height and then using fit function

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web, dagre

I have a graph where I set the dynamic height for the graph because the graph can have different height based on the data we receive from the backend so I am calculating the height based on the number of nodes.

Also, I am using Dagre layout with Left to right hierarchical model but this does not work well for graphs which has more nodes but only some are in left and equal in right.

Because I am also using cy.fit() function to fit the graph in container but if I do that, the height of the container gets really big and fit function is putting the graph in the middle and there is lot of whitespace at the top. What would be the best solution for this scenario?

Example Code Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cytoscape-call-method-child-qm4acb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

In the example, I have added the height to be way more to show the example but is there a way for fit function to start the graph at the top of the container rather than in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pan manually with https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.pan